# How could run python dbus on windows?

Tags: windows, python-3.x, dbus

I'm new to dbus concept and I programming with python 3.5.1 on windows, i read many documents and can't figure out is dbus can work on windows? if so which module I've tried pydubs, pymodbus,... 
please help me should I go to Linux or there is a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a cross-platform (pure Python) implementation, see D-Bus-Next:

https://python-dbus-next.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

For a custom build of D-Bus Python on Windows, see:

http://poquitopicante.blogspot.in/2012/07/building-dbus-python-on-windows-with.html

Using it for public-facing applications could land you in trouble. For mainstream D-Bus use with Python, consider switching to Linux.