# No module named 'dbus' error

Tags: python

I am using the `notify2` module in my project. Apparently, in the `notify2` package, there is a python file named notify2.py, which tries to `import dbus`, which is not installed on my system.

I have tried installing it with `pip install dbus-python`, but it didn't work and I got this "error:

> [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

I'm using Windows 10. How do I make the `notify2` module work? How do I install `dbus` on my computer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How could run python dbus on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37506906/how-could-run-python-dbus-on-windows)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using windows, dbus is not yet implemented in windows OS.
D-Bus IPC work for windows is in progress.

> D-Bus is very portable to any Linux or UNIX flavor, and a port to Windows is in progress.

Here is a [link](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus/) of dbus homepage. You can try porting your code to any linux flavour.