# How to fix notify2 'dbus' error in Python 3 on Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, anaconda, dbus

```
 import notify2 
 notify2.Notification('title')
```

I am using Python 3 with anaconda on Windows 10. When I am running it it's showing

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python Scripting\Upwork RSS Feed Notification\upwork_rss\src\py_s.py", line 56, in <module>
    import notify2
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notify2.py", line 39, in <module>
    import dbus
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dbus'
```

How i can fix the issue?

Comment: it's showing   ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dbus (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for dbus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

install dbus as

```
 pip install dbus-python
```

Comment: now it's showing Building wheels for collected packages: dbus-python
  Building wheel for dbus-python (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\programdata\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\MOHAMM~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_y9q9dyi\\dbus-python\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))

Comment: you are using window system or linux ?

Comment: if window [follow this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37506906/how-could-run-python-dbus-on-windows)

Comment: @sahasrara62 can you please tell for linux ?

Comment: @djangodude you can use this command to install in linux based system also