# Python module dbus-python installation error

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I installed dbus-python with `pip install dbus-python`,

> error: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application occurred.

Here is error from cmd.exe

```
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3f/e7/4edb582d1ffd5ac3c84188deea32e960b5c8c0fe1da56ce70224f85ce542/dbus-python-1.2.8.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: dbus-python
  Building wheel for dbus-python (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Complete output from command 'd:\python\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Dell\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zjhoz7g_\\dbus-python\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-9pjamihn' --python-tag cp37:
  ERROR: running bdist_wheel
  running build
  creating C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zjhoz7g_\dbus-python\build
  creating C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zjhoz7g_\dbus-python\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
  error: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dbus-python
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How could run python dbus on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37506906/how-could-run-python-dbus-on-windows)

Comment: `dbus-python` is not made for windows, it can be used only on linux or mac as the duplicate states.