# How do I fix this dbus installation error?

Tags: python, installation, pip, dbus, notify

when I try to install dbus-python:

pip install dbus-python

I run into this error while installing:

```
Collecting dbus-python
  Using cached dbus-python-1.2.16.tar.gz (576 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for dbus-python, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: dbus-python
    Running setup.py install for dbus-python ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\nana kwamw\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\NANAKW~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-lrjk_2mv\\dbus-python_30409fee025f4702bea7d5058bcbd6da\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\NANAKW~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-lrjk_2mv\\dbus-python_30409fee025f4702bea7d5058bcbd6da\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\NANAKW~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-e6kyrt23\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\nana kwamw\python\python37-32\Include\dbus-python'
         cwd: C:\Users\NANAKW~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lrjk_2mv\dbus-python_30409fee025f4702bea7d5058bcbd6da\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    running install
    running build
    creating C:\Users\NANAKW~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lrjk_2mv\dbus-python_30409fee025f4702bea7d5058bcbd6da\build
    creating C:\Users\NANAKW~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lrjk_2mv\dbus-python_30409fee025f4702bea7d5058bcbd6da\build\temp.win32-3.7
    error: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\nana kwamw\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\NANAKW~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-lrjk_2mv\\dbus-python_30409fee025f4702bea7d5058bcbd6da\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\NANAKW~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-lrjk_2mv\\dbus-python_30409fee025f4702bea7d5058bcbd6da\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\NANAKW~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-e6kyrt23\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\nana kwamw\python\python37-32\Include\dbus-python' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Can someone explain the error and how to fix it?

Comment: Try installing wheel and then dbus-python

Comment: This begs the question why you are trying to install a `dbus` library on Windows, which is not a `dbus` architecture. Probably create a virtual host running a Linux variant which supports `dbus`, and install it there instead.

Comment: D-Bus can be successfully cross-compiled to Windows. Additionally, it's possible to use TCP/IP as the transport protocol to communicate across platforms in a language-agnostic fashion. Whether dbus-python and pydbus support TCP/IP on Windows is a valid question. See http://poquitopicante.blogspot.com/2012/07/building-dbus-python-on-windows-with.html for details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How could run python dbus on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37506906/how-could-run-python-dbus-on-windows)